# Should you delete entries in a MySQL table or have an attribute that is called is_deleted that is set to 1?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I realize this question does not have one answer. But I hope someone can say something about pros and cons about having an attribute that is supposed to keep track of whether an entry is deleted or not.

One pro I can think of is that you have the ability to see entries that was "deleted", for example users that was deleted that can be restored and so on.

Any ideas?

Comment: Only if there is something needed that is not achieved by the transaction-log and the backup procedure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single correct answer to this question. It really depends on what the purpose of the database is, what the table is storing information about and any data protection requirements being enforced.

Leaving useless data in a database will just waste space, so deleting is very useful. But if you will need access to that data in the future, then not actually deleting it is a great idea!

You might want to consider not deleting the data (and just flagging it as being deleted/inactive) if:

- You need to track changes (history) in the table/database;
- You need to be able to restore/un-delete data;
- Different users have different permissions with modifying data;
- The data is super critical;
- Lots of other potential cases!  ;)

Comment: If you have a specific scenario in mind, let us know!

Comment: Thank you! This question almost got me banned from stackoverflow..

Comment: No problem, yeah, they're not too fond of the vague, opinion-based questions! Need another discussion forum for that, I think.